# python split string on whitespace following specific character

Tags: python, regex, split

My first question on Stackoverflow as I haven't been able to find an an answer to it.

I am trying to work out how to split a string in Python, which has the following type of format:

```
'aaaa bbbb cccc:dd eeee:ff ggg hhhh iiii:jjjj kkkk:llll:mm nnn:ooo pppp qqqq:rrr'
```

into the following list items:

- `'aaaa bbbb cccc:dd'`
- `'eeee:ff'`
- `'ggg hhhh iiii:jjjj'`
- `'kkkk:llll:mm'`
- `'nnn:ooo'`
- `'pppp qqqq:rrr'`

Essentially I need to split on the first white space after a colon (':') is detected

I was thinking of looping down the string and splitting on the next whitespace if a colon is detected but I suspect that there may be a more efficient regex that could be used.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I would just match instead of splitting [`\s*(.*?:.*?)(?=\s|$)`](http://regex101.com/r/pT3qU4). Not sure if this is robust enough...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re
a = 'aaaa bbbb cccc:dd eeee:ff ggg hhhh iiii:jjjj kkkk:llll:mm nnn:ooo pppp qqqq:rrr'
print(re.findall(r'([^:]*:[^ ]*) *', a))
```

Comment: interesting quite similar re :)

Comment: Thanks for your help and maybe I could ask an additional question which is how would I change the statement to split on a whitespace before the colon (":")? I think I might need to do both before and after splits.

Comment: @logoverflow do you mean this: re.findall(r'([^:]*|[^:]*:[^ ]*) +', a) I think for such situation, it's better to not use regex for better performance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot use variable-width look-behind, so a regular expression solution is a little harder.

It's easier with a generator function:

```
def after_colon_split(string):
    start = 0
    iter = enumerate(string)
    for i, ch in iter:
        if ch == ':':
            for i, ch in iter:
                if ch == ' ':
                    yield string[start:i]
                    start = i + 1
                    break
    remainder = string[start:]
    if remainder:
         yield remainder
```

Demo:

```
>>> inputstring = 'aaaa bbbb cccc:dd eeee:ff ggg hhhh iiii:jjjj kkkk:llll:mm nnn:ooo pppp qqqq:rrr'
>>> list(after_colon_split(inputstring))
['aaaa bbbb cccc:dd', 'eeee:ff', 'ggg hhhh iiii:jjjj', 'kkkk:llll:mm', 'nnn:ooo', 'pppp qqqq:rrr']
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

ls = list()
fin = list()
string = 'aaaa bbbb cccc:dd eeee:ff ggg hhhh iiii:jjjj kkkk:llll:mm nnn:ooo pppp qqqq:rrr'
for w in string.split():
    if ':' in w:
        ls.append(w)
        fin.append(' '.join(ls))
        ls = []
    else:
        ls.append(w)
for f in fin:
    print f
```

Output:

```
aaaa bbbb cccc:dd
eeee:ff
ggg hhhh iiii:jjjj
kkkk:llll:mm
nnn:ooo
pppp qqqq:rrr
```